# How to calculate EGT Margin for P&W engines (PW1100g) ? (Theta parameter correction)

Tags: aircraft-performance, aircraft-maintenance, engine-design, egt

My goal is to obtain engine baselines and calculate EGT Margin for Pratt&Whitney PW1100g engines (specifically, PW1133GA-JM)

I have a large dataset of engine reports recorded during takeoff. I have applied the following standard formulas for parameter correction:

> $\theta = (T2 + 273.16) / 288.16$
>
> $\delta = P2 / 29.92$
>
> $EGTK = (EGT + 273.16) / \theta ^ {0.84} $
>
> $N1K = N1 / \sqrt{\theta} $
>
> $N2K = N2 / \sqrt{\theta} $

Then, I plotted the corrected values against N1K as shown below.

[image: Corrected EGT and N2 plotted against corrected N1]

Comparing my results to ones found in [this paper](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Study-and-Implementation-of-Algorithms-for-in-of-of-Freitas/c03a5bd685244b3f00c3f1f3d1d760d899d953bd) I found that my EGTK points do not form a straight line therefore I think my correction formulas are wrong.

My questions are:

1. What adjustments should I make to my formulas?
2. How do I consider bleed flags in corrections?

I will appreciate any help and any information related to my problem.